# rails: migration issue with paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, paperclip

I'm trying to migrate the rails app but it fail. the issue in the paperclip gem migration.

I tried to use both way for migration but both of them not work properly:

```
class AddAttachmentImageToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def self.up
    add_attachment :items, :image
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :items, :image
  end
end
```

also tried:

```
class AddAttachmentImageToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_attachment :items, :image
  end
end
```

after run `rails db:migrate` showing error:

```
/Users/zi/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/pry-byebug/control_d_handler.rb:5: warning: control_d_handler's arity of 2 parameters was deprecated (eval_string, pry_instance). Now it gets passed just 1 parameter (pry_instance)
== 20210713231704 AddAttachmentImageToItems: migrating ========================
-- add_attachment(:items, :image)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 3)
/Users/zi/rails/stage_1/db/migrate/20210713231704_add_attachment_image_to_items.rb:3:in `up'
/Users/zi/rails/stage_1/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/zi/rails/stage_1/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/zi/rails/stage_1/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 3)
/Users/zi/rails/stage_1/db/migrate/20210713231704_add_attachment_image_to_items.rb:3:in `up'
/Users/zi/rails/stage_1/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/zi/rails/stage_1/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/zi/rails/stage_1/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: i think paperclip is replaced by ActiveStorage

Answer (score -1):

Found the issue in the ruby version, downgrade to 2.6.8 and migration work properly.